# ssh agent forwarding doesn't forward SHA256

Tags: 14.04, ssh, ssh-agent

`ssh -A IP-address` works always for me, but on one server ubuntu 14.04 doesn't work as it is supposed to.

I have ssh keys on my computer with SHA265 algothithm. But when I go to this server it somehow convert SHA265 to SHA1, which is not allowed for github.

On my PC:

`3072 SHA256:QoKgtzn5XALgRwx2phMUPAF8dHmQ7lOIwiUT49GyXDI deepdows@deepdows-laptop (RSA)`

On the server (14.04):

`3072 a5:7b:c0:22:93:39:0a:82:33:de:d7:0a:b2:35:e9:ec deepdows@deepdows-laptop (RSA)`

Maybe I lack of packages on this server or I need to use another command to make it SHA265?

Comment: Welcome to AU. You need to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu.

Comment: maybe you're just confused by the `FingerPrint` hash change?  https://superuser.com/a/929567 .  Use `ssh-add -E md5 -l` to list keys in ssh-agent in the old format.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019

Comment: @AndrewLowther OK, I see where this hash comes from, but I don't understand why its algorithm from SHA265 to SHA1